# How to check current date between two given dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, case

I need help with a MySQL query to check current date between two given dates and using if condition. Below is my query statement:

```
$selMesQuery="select Subject, Message, PlainMessage, ARActiveTime, ARTimeZone, ARStartTime, AREndTime, ARID, UserId, DispLogo, ContentType from mytable";
```

*ARActiveTime will be **0 or 1**.*

*ARStartTime, AREndTime will be in **datetime format** ex:2015-03-25 22:15:00*

1. If ***ARActiveTime is '0'***, I don't need values of ***ARTimeZone, ARStartTime, AREndTime*** but I need other values.
2. I need the values of ***ARTimeZone, ARStartTime, AREndTime*** along with other values only if ***ARActiveTime is '1' and system time should be in between ARStartTime and AREndTime.***

How do I do this with mysql query statements??

I can do this by executing the given query, checking whether ARActiveTime is 0 or 1 and then get current date, checking from and to dates with php code. But can it be done only with mysql statements only?

May be can it be done using IF condition in query? I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sample data of mysql table:
_________________________________________________________________________________
table header is as per the mysql query given 
__________________________________________________________________________________
sub1 | msg1 | pmsg1 | 0 | 0 |0000-00-00 00:00:00|0000-00-00 00:00:00| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub2 | msg2 | pmsg2 | 1 | 3 |2015-03-12 10:00:00|2015-03-25 22:00:00| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub3 | msg3 | pmsg3 | 1 | 2 |2015-03-10 20:00:00|2015-03-15 20:00:00| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub4 | msg4 | pmsg4 | 0 | 0 |0000-00-00 00:00:00|0000-00-00 00:00:00| 4 | 3 | 0 | 3
_________________________________________________________________________________


desired result:
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub1 | msg1 | pmsg1 |                                                 1 | 1 | 0 | 2
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub2 | msg2 | pmsg2 | 1 | 3 |2015-03-12 10:00:00|2015-03-25 22:00:00| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub3 | msg3 | pmsg3 | 1 | 2 |2015-03-10 20:00:00|2015-03-15 20:00:00| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2
_________________________________________________________________________________
sub4 | msg4 | pmsg4 |                                                 4 | 3 | 0 | 3
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: in mysql it can be done by using case statements

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SUBJECT,
  Message,
  PlainMessage,
  ARActiveTime,
  ARTimeZone,
  ARStartTime,
  AREndTime,
  ARID,
  UserId,
  DispLogo,
  ContentType  FROM mytable WHERE ARActiveTime = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT SUBJECT,
  Message,
  PlainMessage,
  ARActiveTime,
  NULL AS ARTimeZone,
  NULL AS ARStartTime,
  NULL AS AREndTime,
  ARID,
  UserId,
  DispLogo,
  ContentType FROM access_mgmt WHERE ARActiveTime = 0;
```